# django debug messages not working. Only showing - filedescriptor out of range in select()

Tags: python, django, debugging

I'm always getting this error message - A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
File "/Users/chris/Projects/django/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
return self.application(environ, start_response)
File "/Users/chris/Projects/django/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 209, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
 File "/Users/chris/Projects/django/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 200, in get_response
response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
File "/Users/chris/Projects/django/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 235, in         handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/Users/chris/Projects/django/django/views/debug.py", line 77, in technical_500_response
html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
File "/Users/chris/Projects/django/django/views/debug.py", line 335, in get_traceback_html
c = Context(self.get_traceback_data(), use_l10n=False)
File "/Users/chris/Projects/django/django/views/debug.py", line 317, in get_traceback_data
'django_version_info': get_version(),
File "/Users/chris/Projects/django/django/__init__.py", line 8, in get_version
return get_version(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/chris/Projects/django/django/utils/version.py", line 26, in get_version
git_changeset = get_git_changeset()
File "/Users/chris/Projects/django/django/utils/version.py", line 48, in get_git_changeset
timestamp = git_log.communicate()[0]
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 806, in communicate
return self._communicate(input)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1384, in _communicate
stdout, stderr = self._communicate_with_select(input)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1485, in _communicate_with_select
rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(read_set, write_set, [])
ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()
```

Anyone have any ideas? This seems to have only happened after upgrading to django 1.7 but I'm not sure about that

Comment: Is your personal project also named "django"? That can bring all kinds of problems...

Comment: Django 1.7 is not even out - why are you using it?

Comment: I checked out the django source to my project directory, along side my main projects. If that's a problem, let me know. I'm on 1.7 because I wanted migrations from the start, and thought that would be easier than 1.6 and south. Should and can I migrate back to 1.6 and south? Is  it the same migration format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updated to the latest version of django, and the error has gone. Feel a bit stupid using 1.7 rather than 1.6 and south, but there you go.

Comment: Have just downgraded to 1.6 and everything is working far better. It also wasn't very hard to switch to south.